# How can I remove the desktop shortcut after uninstalling a UWP app

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, shortcut-file

I used this code to create a desktop shortcut programmatically as it's not possible to create using any package capabilities

```
object shDesktop = (object)"Desktop";
            WshShell shell = new WshShell();
            string shortcutAddress = (string)shell.SpecialFolders.Item(ref shDesktop) + @"\Appss Windows Messenger.lnk";
            IWshShortcut shortcut = (IWshShortcut)shell.CreateShortcut(shortcutAddress);
            shortcut.Description = ClientName;
            shortcut.Hotkey = "Ctrl+Shift+N";
            shortcut.TargetPath = @"shell:AppsFolder\WindowsMessenger_fwsgascccvxc0!App";
            shortcut.Save();
```

Is there any way to remove this shortcut after uninstalling the app.

Comment: UWP platform does not support `Windows Script Host Object Mode`, do you develop UWP app?

Comment: I have a WPF component which I use in my UWP app using desktop bridge